# Fringe indicators very tiny

Tags: fringe

My fringe indicators have become extremely tiny. Left side is flycheck, right side is git-gutter-fringe. So different packages, both extremely tiny.

My font might look huge, but it's not; it's 12. Doesn't matter if I change my font, or font size (the fringe doesn't scale).

I've tried `(fringe-mode 20)` and `(set-font-face 'fringe nil :height 100)`. Linum is fine.

My emacs config is pretty simple and it works fine on my Mac. Did a straight copy over to Windows 10.

This is official Emacs build for Windows 10 (installed via choco).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a scaling issue (or lack thereof).

Example: on Windows 4k resolution with 200% scaling, the fringe is tiny. But with 100% scaling they appear ok.

The official bug report is at https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31203

Answer (score 0):

Would it help if you set different values? For example,

```
  (set-fringe-mode '(2 . 4)) ;; Left: 2px; Right: 4px
```